# Distribution signing certificates error?

Tags: xcode, app-store

I am trying to launch app on iTunes store it shows some distribution certificate issues.I already have created the developer as well as distribution provisioning certificates. I am attaching  the screen shots what type of error is it?

[image]

Comment: are you install this cf in your key chain ?

Comment: yes already installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your distribution certificates has expired I think. Please check it in your keychain Access.

[image]

Check whether its green ticked or not. If yes download a new one and install it

Comment: delete the expired certificates and request a new one from keychain Access -->CERTIFICATE ASSISTANT and request a new one